# How to deploy Winforms Entity Framework Code First approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I develop a WinForms app and using Entity Framework code-first approach to create a database in my local development machine.  Everything works fine and I can create a database using add migration and update database.

How I can deploy the database to my production server?  I deploy the WinForms app using the ClickOnce method in Visual Studio to generate the installation file.  How I can/should deploy the database to a production server?  The way I can figure out is to go to development DB and generate a script for the table and run in a production database server.  Another way is to run the add migration and update database one more time where the connection string is a point to a production database.

In future, if the model change or new model add; what is the way to update the table?

Comment: Are Automatic Migrations enabled? You can run Migration via a DatabaseInitializer or manually in Package Management Console. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: as @SergeyVishnevsky told one way is to enable AutomaticMigrations, another way can contain use database.EnsureCreate()  or databse.Migrate() in your project start up.